# I allow only one hyphen (-) in regex

Tags: regex

I have a text box where i get the last name of user. How do I allow only one hyphen (-) in a regular expression?

```
^([a-z A-Z]*-){1}[a-z A-Z]*$
```

Comment: Your regex allows only one hyphen, so what is your problem?

Answer (score 3):

you can use negative lookahead to reject strings having more than one hyphen:

```
^(?![^-]+-[^-]+-)[a-zA-Z- ]+$
```

---

[Matched](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5E%28%3F%21%5B%5E-%5D%2B-%5B%5E-%5D%2B-%29%5Ba-zA-Z-+%5D%2B%24&str=abcd) demo on debuggex.

[Another Matched](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5E%28%3F%21%5B%5E-%5D%2B-%5B%5E-%5D%2B-%29%5Ba-zA-Z-+%5D%2B%24&str=abcd-efgh) demo on debuggex.

[Not Matched Demo](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5E%28%3F%21%5B%5E-%5D%2B-%5B%5E-%5D%2B-%29%5Ba-zA-Z-+%5D%2B%24&str=abcd-efgh-ijkl) demo on debuggex.

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression allow exactly one `-`. but I assume that you want to mach "Smith", "Smith-Kennedy", but not "Smith-", to do this you just must move the hyphen to the second group:

```
^[a-z A-Z]+(-[a-z A-Z]+)?$
```

BTW, in almost all cases when `*` is used `+` is the better solution.

Comment: Your regex allows a space. How do i catch a space?

Comment: No it doesnt, regular exprssion above doesn't allow a single space to be mached.

Comment: Above regex allows space. You need to remove it to prevent space to be allowed. like this `^[a-zA-Z]+(-[a-zA-Z]+)?$`. Test it here : https://regex101.com/r/MYdavn/1

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want up to 1 hyphen. If so, the regex you want is

```
^[a-z A-Z]*-?[a-z A-Z]*$
```

You can visualize it on [www.debuggex.com](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5E%5Ba-z%20A-Z%5D%2a-?%5Ba-z%20A-Z%5D%2a%24&str=Hello%20world-asdf).

Answer (score 0):

A problem with your regex is that it forces the user to put a `-`. You can use `?` to make it optional :

```
^[a-z A-Z]*\-?[a-zA-Z]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

If it matches `.*-.*-`, then you have more than one hyphen and such string should not be accepted