# How do I allow only one hyphen (-),only one space( ),only one apostrophe (') in a regular expression

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

I have a text box where i get the last name of user. How do I allow only one hyphen (-),only one space( ),only one apostrophe (') in a regular expression

Comment: You asked a [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827051/i-allow-only-one-hyphen-in-regex/15827134#15827134) question about 20 minutes ago.

Comment: Do you mean it has to have 1 of all 3? or that it can have only one each of any of the three? Or that it can only have one of the three?  Also, you do know that some people have multiple first and last names, and some people have multiple hyphenated names, and some people have apostrophe's in both their first name and last name, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for each of the 3 chars you want to avoid :

```
^(?!.*-.*-.*)(?!.*'.*'.*)(?!.*\s.*\s.*)[a-zA-Z- ']+$
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you need a regular expression at all (unless you specifically need the hyphen, space, and apostrophe to be in a particular position within the string which you have not specified).

Just go through the string character by character and count up the hyphens, spaces, and apostrophes.

Regexes are good for matching character patterns, and can be very powerful, but IMHO there are some cases where they are not only overkill, but can simply be the wrong tool for the job.